# Java gui second function of frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

i need help of my program because ill wanna do to put a password and username to my program so if the username is test && password is 12345 my program will appear a new frame but unfortunately my second didnt work for my label,button and etc here is my code so far .

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SwapFields extends JFrame

{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwapFields frameTabel = new SwapFields();
    }

        JButton blogin = new JButton("Login");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JTextField txuser = new JTextField(15);
        JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(15);
        JLabel lab = new JLabel("Username :");
        JLabel pas = new JLabel("Password :");
        JLabel cos;
        //JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton y1;
        JButton y2;

    SwapFields()
        {
            super("Enter Your Account !");
            setSize(300,200);
            setLocation(500,280);
            panel.setLayout (null);


            txuser.setBounds(90,30,150,20);
            pass.setBounds(90,65,150,20);
            blogin.setBounds(110,100,80,20);
            lab.setBounds(15,28,150,20);
            pas.setBounds(15,63,150,20);

            panel.add(lab);
            panel.add(pas);
            panel.add(blogin);
            panel.add(txuser);
            panel.add(pass);

            getContentPane().add(panel);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
            actionlogin();
        }

            public void actionlogin()
        {
            blogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
             {
                String puname = txuser.getText();
                String ppaswd = pass.getText();
                if(puname.equals("test") && ppaswd.equals("12345"))
            {

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Customer");
                JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setSize(300,200);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


                    cos = new JLabel("Do you have a Customer ?");
                    y1 = new JButton("Yes");
                    y2 = new JButton("No");


                        panel1.setLayout(null);
                        cos.setBounds(70,30,150,20);
                        y1.setBounds(80,65,150,20);
                        y2.setBounds(140,65,150,20);

                        y1.setSize(55,30);
                        y2.setSize(55,30);
                        panel1.add(y1);
                        panel1.add(y2);
                        panel1.add(cos);
                        getContentPane().add(panel1);
//

                    dispose();
            }
            else
                {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong Password / Username");
                    txuser.setText("");
                    pass.setText("");
                    txuser.requestFocus();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add your new controls/panels etc to your original frame not the new frame.

```
getContentPane().add(panel1);
```

Should probably be accessing the content pane in the new frame...

Comment: ill tried also that sir but only the frame will appear if the username and password is correct . no label appear on my second frame

Answer (score 3):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class NewClass extends JFrame

{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        NewClass frameTabel = new NewClass();
    }

        JButton blogin = new JButton("Login");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JTextField txuser = new JTextField(15);
        JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(15);
        JLabel lab = new JLabel("Username :");
        JLabel pas = new JLabel("Password :");
        JLabel cos;
        //JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton y1;
        JButton y2;

    NewClass()
        {
            super("Enter Your Account !");
            setSize(300,200);
            setLocation(500,280);
            panel.setLayout (null);


            txuser.setBounds(90,30,150,20);
            pass.setBounds(90,65,150,20);
            blogin.setBounds(110,100,80,20);
            lab.setBounds(15,28,150,20);
            pas.setBounds(15,63,150,20);

            panel.add(lab);
            panel.add(pas);
            panel.add(blogin);
            panel.add(txuser);
            panel.add(pass);

            getContentPane().add(panel);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
            actionlogin();
        }

            public void actionlogin()
        {
            blogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
             {
                String puname = txuser.getText();
                String ppaswd = pass.getText();
                if(puname.equals("test") && ppaswd.equals("12345"))
            {

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Customer");
                JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setSize(300,200);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout());

                    cos = new JLabel("Do you have a Customer ?");
                    y1 = new JButton("Yes");
                    y2 = new JButton("No");


                        panel1.setLayout(null);
                        cos.setBounds(70,30,150,20);
                        y1.setBounds(80,65,150,20);
                        y2.setBounds(140,65,150,20);

                        y1.setSize(55,30);
                        y2.setSize(55,30);
                        panel1.add(y1);
                        panel1.add(y2);
                        panel1.add(cos);
//                        panel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
//                        getContentPane().add(panel1);
//
                        frame.add(panel1);

                    dispose();
            }
            else
                {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong Password / Username");
                    txuser.setText("");
                    pass.setText("");
                    txuser.requestFocus();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: i will change my panel1.setLayout(null); into setLayout(new FlowLayout()); ? am i right ?

Comment: java.lang.Error: Do not use SwapFields.setLayout() use SwapFields.getContentPane().setLayout() instead
 at javax.swing.JFrame.createRootPaneException(JFrame.java:465)
 at javax.swing.JFrame.setLayout(JFrame.java:531)
 at SwapFields$1.actionPerformed(SwapFields.java:74)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1786)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$ForwardActionEvents.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1839)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:420)

Comment: @CoderShei First do `frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());`

Comment: @CoderShei Only setting `frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());` is working for me. and must add `panel1` in `frame`. No need of setting layout to `panel1`

Comment: i think i have a problem with my version . sir can you edit my work ? to find if the version is problem

Comment: @CoderShei see the edited answer.. Check `frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));`

Comment: ill got error sir :3 . idont know what happened can you edit my program sir to you want to do or your suggestion because ill get confusing . idont know if my syntax or the version of JCreator is the problem .

Comment: @CoderShei now check it

Comment: ill got error again . so i found that the version is the problem :3 . sir do you have any idea where can i DL ide like netbeans for java ?

Comment: Select `JDK 7u51 & NetBeans 7.4` from this site and download it 

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnjp

Comment: Thankyou very very very much sir :) . i hope it will run in netbeans . thanks godbless